# Недавно некоторые цифры изменились на float (1.0, 4.0) и.т.д

Tags: google-apps-script

Я создаю в коде документ и заполняю его данными. Примерно неделю назад некоторые цифры, например количество штук, стали печататься как 1.0 шт. Пытался в коде явно приводить к int, но пока не нашел в чем проблема. Может вы в курсе про какое-то обновление итд?

Вижу надпись что какая-то новая среда теперь.

Вот код:

```
function newTestAutofill(){
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveRange();
  var currentData = data.getDisplayValues();
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("asdfasdfafsd");


  for(var i=0;i<currentData.length;i++){
  var filenumber = getNumber(folder);
  var formula = data.getCell(i+1,6).getFormula(); 

 var strarr = currentData[i][1].split("\n");
 var formarr = formula.substr(1).split("+");
   if(formula==""&&strarr.length!=1){
   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast((i+1)+"\n Есть перенос строки в товарах, но отсутствует формула.\nФайл не создан.","Внимание!",-1);
    continue;
   } 
   if(strarr.length>formarr.length){
       SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast((i+1)+"\n Товаров больше чем цен в формуле.\nФайл не создан.","Внимание!",-1);
        continue;
   }
  var docid = DriveApp.getFileById("asdfafa").makeCopy(filenumber,folder).getId();
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docid);
  var body = doc.getActiveSection();  
  var searchElement = body.findElement(DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE);
  var element = searchElement.getElement();
  var table = element.asTable();
   table.removeRow(1);
   body.replaceText("%NUMBER%", filenumber);
   body.replaceText("%DATE%", getDate(currentData[i][0]));
   body.replaceText("%NAME%", currentData[i][2]);
   //body.replaceText("%ADRESS%", currentData[i][4]);
   body.replaceText("%PHONE%", currentData[i][3]);
   body.replaceText("%SUM%", num2str(currentData[i][5]));
   body.replaceText("%COUNT%", strarr.length);

   for(var j=0;j<strarr.length;j++){
      var row = table.appendTableRow();
      row.appendTableCell(j+1).setPaddingTop(0).setPaddingBottom(0);
      row.appendTableCell(strarr[j]).setPaddingTop(0).setPaddingBottom(0);
      row.appendTableCell(1).setPaddingTop(0).setPaddingBottom(0);
      row.appendTableCell("шт").setPaddingTop(0).setPaddingBottom(0);
     if(strarr.length==1){
      row.appendTableCell(currentData[i][5]).setPaddingTop(0).setPaddingBottom(0);
      row.appendTableCell(currentData[i][5]).setPaddingTop(0).setPaddingBottom(0);
     }else{
      row.appendTableCell(formarr[j]).setPaddingTop(0).setPaddingBottom(0);
      row.appendTableCell(formarr[j]).setPaddingTop(0).setPaddingBottom(0);
     }
   }

  body.replaceText("%PRICE%", currentData[i][5]);    

  doc.saveAndClose()
  }

}
```

Comment: Попроще пример приведите - нет никакого смысла во всем в этом ковыряться.

Comment: Какие данные отображаются в Таблице на данный момент?

Comment: @contributorpw было "1 шт" - стало "1.0 шт". Было "3", стало "3.0". Подстановка в этих местах в код parseInt(); не помогает.

Comment: Постараюсь сделать код проще и показать

Comment: Приведите пример данных, пожалуйста.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать старую среду выполнения (включается/выключается в меню редактора скриптов или в манифесте)

Comment: @СергейПряничкин благодарю, помогло!